# Usage of ThreadPoolExecutor after extending

Tags: java, concurrency

According to Java concurrency in practice if we want to add logging, timing, monitoring  facility to ThreadPoolExecutor then we should extend it. Suppose if we extend it  like below:

```
// code taken from java concurrency in practice

public class TimingThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor 
{
private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTime
        = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("TimingThreadPool");
private final AtomicLong numTasks = new AtomicLong();
private final AtomicLong totalTime = new AtomicLong();

protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
    log.fine(String.format("Thread %s: start %s", t, r));
    startTime.set(System.nanoTime());
}

protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    try {
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long taskTime = endTime - startTime.get();
        numTasks.incrementAndGet();
        totalTime.addAndGet(taskTime);
        log.fine(String.format("Thread %s: end %s, time=%dns",
                t, r, taskTime));
    } finally {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
    }
}

protected void terminated() {
    try {
        log.info(String.format("Terminated: avg time=%dns",
                totalTime.get() / numTasks.get()));
    } finally {
        super.terminated();
    }
}
}
```

Here my doubt is how will you use this class, because if you create ExecutorService it always returns an instance of ThreadPoolExecutor. So how will u plug this class to show the loggings (need client code to use this).

Thanks in advance!!! Sorry if i made any mistake while mentioning the question.

Comment: `ExecutorService timedExecutor = new TimingThreadPool(...);` ?

Comment: "if you create ExecutorService" How do you usually create `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @assylias I have small doubt here. Is the ThreadPoolExecutor instance is shared by all the worker threads. If yes then the method beforeExecute(...) and afterExecute(...) shouldn't be synchronized? If the answer is no then is the reason is" the local variables are assigned in thread stack and state variables are thread confined / atomic". Please share ur feedback. thanks.

Comment: @user2030415 That is a very different question and you should probably ask it separately. Your current design is suspicious - in particular, your use of ThreadLocal does not make sense here as I believe that beforeExecute will be run in the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

Your class is missing constuctors, it wont work without them

```
public class TimingThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public TimingThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Besides you could take a look at `Executors` implementation and do something similar in your class

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new TimingThreadPool(nThreads, nThreads,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```